# typescript syntax when assigning default values

Tags: typescript, syntax

I have something like this:

`const {
  a: b = ''
} = c;`

and later on, many validations are done based on the value at `b`, but, according to me, that value was assigned '', is this correct?

Comment: I have no idea what did you mean!
Are you saying the value of b = '' no matter the values at c?

Comment: Thanks @zerkms. I was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are assigned the default value if their value is undefined. So if `c.a` is undefined you would be correct.

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) are the docs on destructuring if you want more information.

Comment: Are you saying the value of b = '' no matter the values at c?

Comment: @Eduardo `b` is assigned an empty string `''` only if `c.a` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Eduardo The code you wrote basically says assign b to c.a unless c.a is undefined then assign b to ''. so if c.a is equal to 'hello' b will also be equal to 'hello'. however, if c.a is undefined then b will be set to the default value of ''